# pandas data frame add value to a set in a column of a specified row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add a value to a set in a column of a specified row.
For instance I have: (username and tags are column names)

```
username  tags
qwe       (happy)
```

And I want to change that to:

```
username  tags
qwe       (happy, friendly)
```

To be specific, I want to first search for that row using the username "qwe", and insert into the tags column of that username another value. Please note that the tags are in sets.

What function in dataframe can I use? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get the row of the searched user and add the new tag to the set of tags in that row. Since it is a `set`, you have to use `.add`.

If your 'username' field is not the index -

```
df[df['username']=='qwe']['tags'].values[0].add(tag)
```

If your 'username' field is the index -

```
df.loc['qwe']['tags'].add(tag)
```

Sample data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
                   'tags': [set(), set(), set(), set()]})
```

Code:

```
def add_tag(user, tag):
    df[df['user']==user]['tags'].values[0].add(tag)

add_tag('two', 'happy')
add_tag('two', 'friendly')
add_tag('two', 'friendly')
```

Result:

```
    user               tags
0    one                 {}
1    two  {friendly, happy}
2  three                 {}
3   four                 {}
```